# How to open chrome with extension using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to programming, so what I trying do is open chrome with extension. After doing some search i found this link : https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/amp/

However it talks about Java which I have no clue... So I want to incorporate the same method with VBA ... Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is from when I set up two profiles: one with javascript enabled and the other without. If you have already got the extension installed in the profile it should load when you pass the correct path. In my experience I found it more reliable to create the profile and launch Chrome via Selenium and then add the extension. For example, with the script below I opened Chrome app store for one of my profiles and manually added Usersnap extension. Now, when I launch this profile again it is present.

Note: I set up profiles by launching selenium chrome and entering `chrome://version/` then copying the `Profile Path` to re-use.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AddExtension()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Const URL = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Usersnap"
    Const NO_JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
    Const JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    With d
        .SetProfile JS_PROFILE, True   'NO_JS_PROFILE, True 
        .get URL
         Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

These two examples are direct from the author himself and available on GitHub

```
Private Sub Use_Chrome_With_Extension()
  ' To download an extension:
  ' http://chrome-extension-downloader.com
  ' To manage the extension preferences:
  ' Developper Tools > Resources > Local Storage > chrome-extension://...

  Dim driver As New ChromeDriver
  driver.AddExtension "C:\Users\florent\Downloads\Personal-Blocklist-(by-Google)_v2.6.1.crx"
  driver.SetPreference "plugins.plugins_disabled", Array("Adobe Flash Player")
  driver.Get "chrome-extension://nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef/manager.html"
  driver.ExecuteScript "localStorage.setItem('blocklist', '[""wikipedia.org""]');"

  driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"
  driver.Quit
End Sub


Private Sub Use_Firefox_With_Extension()
  ' To download an extension, use a browser other than Firefox

  Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
  driver.AddExtension "C:\Users\florent\Downloads\firebug-2.0.12-fx.xpi"
  driver.SetPreference "extensions.firebug.showFirstRunPage", False

  driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"
  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

---

The above shows the 2 ways to load with extension (by `Load a Chrome Extension` by providing a path argument, creating a `Custom Chrome Profile` and passing the path to that. More info [here](https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/).

---

**Walk through of setting a temp profile** (conversation between @qharr & @YasserKhalil)

```
'Run This Procedure 'GetInfo' First
'----------------------------------
Sub GetInfo()
Dim d As WebDriver

Set d = New ChromeDriver
Const URL = "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/"

With d
    .Start "Chrome"
    .get URL
    Stop
End With
End Sub

'In The Browser Replace The Current URL With chrome://version/ And Press Enter
'Make A Note Of The Profile Path And Use It In This Procedure 'AddExtension'
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub AddExtension()
Dim d As WebDriver

Const MY_PROFILE As String = 
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\Selenium\scoped_dir6268_2742\Default"
Set d = New ChromeDriver
Const URL = "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/"

With d
    .SetProfile MY_PROFILE, True
    .get URL
    Stop
    .Quit
End With
End Sub

'Now Navigate And Install Your Extension Manually
'------------------------------------------------

'Relaunch browser and extension should be present
'------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hi QHarr, i have already downloaded the examples file. But I am not sure how to suit my needs. The extension i am trying to open is ultrasurf

Comment: Also, just to let you know. The extension is already added to the normal chrome.

Comment: Ok... updating with a version I used for javascript testing

Comment: Thanks for all the help !!! So if replace the word "Usersnap" with my program name it should work, correct ?

Comment: No. You would replace the profile path with your path to the profile. My experience was that I needed to add the extension after launching the profile from selenium and not by creating a user profile via chrome settings.

Comment: I am so sorry, as l stated eariler l do not have any programming knowledge. So let me try and see if it works for me !!!

Comment: Hi again, the code is working fine however, when I re-run the code it shows as the chrome did not shutdown properly. I have used .quit and .Close method but still it gives the same error. So at the end i did close the chrome by manually clicking red X at the top right corner and it got fixed. So now could you please help me out with a code to do sendkeys option with alt+f4.

Comment: @Qharr It has been a while !! Happy New year. I just tried the above code to close chrome using sendkeys. however, it does not work the code runs successfully but the nothing is closed.

Comment: @David Happy new year. Are you using my exact script?

Comment: Yes !! Just to let you know, It did close the chrome when I did F5 on the script, The truth is it did not close by the sendkeys, it got closed after the code runs. so I did F9 on the "End With" line and run the script still the chrome was present.

Comment: I will have to have a gander. Remind me.... what was the error message? You said in the original answer sometimes .Quit doesn't close Chrome loaded from profile ?

Comment: For the first time code runs perfectly, when i try to re-run again as soon the chrome opens, on the right top corner of the window it says that "The Chrome did not shutdown properly would you like to restore".  This does not happen when i close the Chrome manually by clicking the red X.  Note : To close the chrome manually i do F9 in the code before the End sub line so the code stops and then i close the chrome.