# Download wistia links using selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

The following code opens multiple links (wistia links)

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

Set bot = New ChromeDriver
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Links")
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

Rem https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/n3tweojtus
With bot
    .Start "Chrome"
    .Get arr(1)

    For i = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
            .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", arr(i)
            .SwitchToNextWindow
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

How can I save the video to the disk ..?
I noticed that IDM panel doesn't appear in the selenium driver ..
What is the easiest way to download multiple links (the links are in A2:A & last row)?

I have tried this line

```
    With bot
    .AddExtension ThisWorkbook.Path & "\extension_6_33_2_0.crx"
```

and I noticed the extension has been added but the code hangs and doesn't open any of the existing links

Comment: I just need to make the IDM panel appears in the selenium driver

Comment: Can you share a couple of urls and explain what IDM panel is in plain english? Also, point out which videos you are expecting to download from those urls.

Comment: Is this an example url which also houses the video? And are these the actual urls in your worksheet? https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/n3tweojtus

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: How can I enable the IDM extension in the selenium driver? That would solve the situation

Comment: load the profile you have created via selenium and enable it manually - hopefully that sets it in the preferences for the profile on disk. Note there are instructions that seem to indicate no download and inline play only.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I set the default profile as I tried but it doesn't seem to work for me and no extensions loaded?

Comment: I answered this in a different question of yours I think

Comment: Thanks a lot. I remember that but I have searched and didn't reach the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351800/how-to-open-chrome-with-extension-using-selenium-vba/53351948#53351948  We discussed but was someone else's question I think.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way in selenium to click on the IDM little panel that enables the users to download?

Comment: Don’t know as I don’t have whatever that is