# Error with Chrome profile selection with Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to open a new Chromedriver session with a selected profile "Profile 1". But I also want to keep other Chrome window/session open (which has the default profile).

I tried this piece of code, it opens the new Chrome windows correctly and with "Profile 1" as I want.
But I then get following error from VBA.

```
Private Sub Use_Chrome_With_Custom_profile_name()
  ' Profiles folder : %APPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Profiles
  ' Note that with Chrome the profile is always persistant

  Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

  driver.AddArgument "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
  driver.AddArgument "--profile-directory=Profile 1"

  driver.Get "https://www.google.co.uk"
  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

[image]

If I skip (commenting it) this line then Chrome does'nt open with Profile 1:

```
'driver.AddArgument "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

Comment: Did you try launching with separate webdriver instances?

Comment: @QHarr What do you mean with separate instances in this case? For better clarity,Chrome session 1 (with default profile) is open in standard way (not by VBA or programmatically, then not through chromedriver. Only session 2 (with Profile 1) has been called from VBA and Chromedriver

Comment: Open both with separate chromedrivers.

Comment: @QHarr I Can't understand.The first session is not actually opened by chromedriver, it's just a Chrome session, open manually for manual navigation purpose. The second session only is open with Chromedriver via VBA

Comment: Does this error occur even when no other chrome window open and you attempt to launch the profile 1? See the steps here where profile is part of folder path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351800/how-to-open-chrome-with-extension-using-selenium-vba/53351948#53351948

Comment: @QHarr No if no other chrome windows are open I don't get this error and Profile 1 is working fine. But I need them to be open

Comment: Did you try having profile on path and setting as shown in link I shared?

Comment: @QHarr sure I tried but still not working. Hope I well understood. I added this line just after `driver.AddArgument`: `driver.SetProfile "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1", True`

Comment: And you confirmed it is the correct path for the profile? Mind you that should prompt a different error.

Comment: Shame @DebanjanB likely hasn't seen this as he usually has very useful insight.

Comment: @QHarr yes I confirm it's the correct path. In fact Chrome loads correctly with "Profile 1" and unfortunately returns error just after

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim driver As New WebDriver

    Const URL = "https://www.google.co.uk"
    Const JS_PROFILE As String = _
    "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    With driver
        .SetProfile JS_PROFILE, True
        .Get URL
    End With
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).