# Open Chrome with options

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With this script I open Chrome in Selenium VBA

```
Public Sub browser_open()
Set bot = New ChromeDriver
bot.Start "chrome", "http://some_site"
bot.get "/"
End Sub
```

Is it possible to open Chrome using the options `--kiosk-printing`, so that printing takes place without dialogue?

Comment: Try with set-preference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53351948/6241235 Or set-up a profile with that setting and use that profile: https://support.vendhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/201378390-Enable-kiosk-printing-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows  <<< that is first link I found so you can probably find a better one.

Comment: Don't forget to post as an answer